# Why is there no ouput in the System Console?

Tags: python, command-line

I'm running Blender 2.78a on Windows. Running the python script shown below, there is no output in the system console.

How can I direct output to the console?

[image]

Comment: Is that console the one that opens when you press Show Console?

Comment: Is there a chance you have accidentally set the console foreground / background colours both to black?

Comment: The console windows is opened by by clicking the Windows menu and then "Toggle System Console". (This is on windows 10) I moved the console window on top of the Blender GUI, and added the some text for explanation, just for the screen shoot.

Comment: I have not changed any colors, tried a few different themes, e.g. Elysium and Ubuntu Ambiance, but the colors in the console window are the same. Does it work on your machine, do you have output in the console?

Comment: I know this may seem like a stupid suggestion, but it has happened to me: Have you tried scrolling up in the console window? From the scrollbar in that screenshot, either output *is* getting printed but it is for some reason black or you have scrolled down so the printed output is not in view.

Comment: No, the console is black, scrolling forth and back, using different theme presets. But I have identified where part of the problem is, I will use the answer your question below

Answer (score 1):

I now can conclude that the black system console window is with Blender 2.78a under [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/), running from a usb drive. When downloading the zip file directly from [blender.org](https://www.blender.org/download/), and unzipping, the console works as described in the manual.

Comment: Always get the software from the source as much as possible. Since it's opensource you will nv know if you got the programme with malicious code added to it if it's from a non official source.

Comment: If you download an official Blender as zip file it already is "portable". There is no need to get it from somewhere else for that.